# Throwing exception causes SIGSEGV on OSX 10.11.4 + clang

Tags: c++, macos, exception

Given the following code:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class exception_base : public runtime_error {
public:
    exception_base() 
    : runtime_error(string()) { }
};

class my_exception : public exception_base {
public:

};

int main() {
    throw my_exception();
}
```

This works fine on GNU/Linux and Windows and used to work fine on OSX before the latest update to version 10.11.4. By fine I mean since nothing catches the exception, `std::terminate` is called.

However, on OSX 10.11.4 using clang (LLVM 7.3.0), the program crashes with segmentation fault. The stack trace is not helpful:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000100000ad1 in main () at test.cpp:17
17      throw my_exception();
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000100000ad1 in main () at test.cpp:17
(gdb)
```

Nor is what valgrind has to say about this:

```
==6500== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6500==  General Protection Fault
==6500==    at 0x100000AD1: main (test.cpp:17)
```

I don't think that code violates the standard in any way. Am I missing something here?

Note that even if I add a try-catch around the `throw` the code still crashes due to SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the disassembly, you will see that a general-protection (GP) exception is occurring on an SSE `movaps` instruction:

```
a.out`main:
    0x100000ad0 :   pushq  %rbp
    0x100000ad1 :   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000ad4 :   subq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x100000ad8 :   movl   $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
    0x100000adf :  movl   $0x10, %eax
    0x100000ae4 :  movl   %eax, %edi
    0x100000ae6 :  callq  0x100000dea               ; symbol stub for: __cxa_allocate_exception
    0x100000aeb :  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x100000aee :  xorps  %xmm0, %xmm0
->  0x100000af1 :  movaps %xmm0, (%rax)
    0x100000af4 :  movq   %rdi, -0x20(%rbp)
    0x100000af8 :  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x100000afb :  callq  0x100000b40               ; my_exception::my_exception
...
```

Before the my_exception::my_exception() constructor is even called, a `movaps` instruction is used to zero out the block of memory returned by __cxa_allocate_exception(size_t). However, this pointer (0x0000000100103498 in my case) is not guaranteed to be 16-byte aligned. When the source or destination operand of a `movaps` instruction is a memory operand, the operand **must** be aligned on a 16-byte boundary or else a GP exception is generated.

One way to fix the problem temporarily is to compile without SSE instructions (`-mno-sse`). It's not an ideal solution because SSE instructions can improve performance.

I think that this is related to http://reviews.llvm.org/D18479 :

> [r246985](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=246985) made changes to give a higher alignment for exception objects on the grounds that Itanium says _Unwind_Exception should be "double-word" aligned and the structure is normally declared with `__attribute__((aligned))` guaranteeing 16-byte alignment. It turns out that libc++abi doesn't declare the structure with `__attribute__((aligned))` and therefore only guarantees 8-byte alignment on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms. This caused a crash in some cases when the backend emitted SIMD store instructions that requires 16-byte alignment (such as `movaps`).
>
> This patch makes ItaniumCXXABI::getAlignmentOfExnObject return an 8-byte alignment on Darwin to fix the crash.

.. which patch was committed on March 31, 2016 as [r264998](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=264998).

There's also https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24604 and https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27208 which appear related.

**UPDATE** I installed Xcode 7.3.1 (released yesterday) and the problem appears to be fixed; the generated assembly is now:

```
a.out`main:
    0x100000ac0 :   pushq  %rbp
    0x100000ac1 :   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000ac4 :   subq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x100000ac8 :   movl   $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
    0x100000acf :  movl   $0x10, %eax
    0x100000ad4 :  movl   %eax, %edi
    0x100000ad6 :  callq  0x100000dea               ; symbol stub for: __cxa_allocate_exception
    0x100000adb :  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x100000ade :  movq   $0x0, 0x8(%rax)
    0x100000ae6 :  movq   $0x0, (%rax)
    0x100000aed :  movq   %rdi, -0x20(%rbp)
    0x100000af1 :  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x100000af4 :  callq  0x100000b40               ; my_exception::my_exception
...
```

Comment: Great answer! I can't believe this little piece of code breaks the compiler. Hope the patch is pushed soon... Thanks!

Comment: @mfontanini Looks like the patch has already been pushed. I tested clang-703.0.31 / Xcode 7.3.1 and the generated assembly no longer uses a `movaps` instruction.